# Newly discovered (by mainstream investors) asset chart/theory

Tags: reference-request, price-theory

I was reading an article about bitcoin in which a description was given of a chart/theory related to investor hype when an investment is first discovered by the mainstream. I've been unable to locate the article a second time. The phenomenon is as follows. There is an initial hype period during which the price soars, followed by a resounding crash, and finally a much more sustainably trajectory of growth. I'm looking for any information on this phenomenon. Who's work it is, article, paper, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the [Gartner Hype Cycle](http://www.gartner.com/technology/research/methodologies/hype-cycle.jsp).